# AWS S3 Javascript SDK - download file from private bucket with key and secret in browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I have csv file in S3 private bucket that I have created key to access. I am successfully using key and secret in Python to download the csv file to disk.

Now I am trying the [AWSJavaScriptSDK](http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html) to use JavaScript in the browser to retrieve the csv file.

Note this is something I will use only on my computer so not concerned about having key and secret in page.

I have setup CORS properly and am successfully able to get the file name using the script below. I have also tried a variation of this code that lists all files in bucket which also works. So I am authenticating and accessing the bucket properly.

But I cannot find any non Node.js examples to retrieve the csv file and download it to disk using the AWSJavaScriptSDK for JavaScript in the browser.

```
<div id="status"></div>
<ul id="objects"></ul>

<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.6.3.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

    AWS.config.accessKeyId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    AWS.config.secretAccessKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

    // create the AWS.Request object
    var bucket = new AWS.S3();

    bucket.getObject({
        Bucket: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
        Key: 'filename.csv'})
        .on('success', function(response) {               
            console.log("Key was", response.request.params.Key );
        }).send();    


</script>
```

My ultimate goal is to use the csv file in a D3.js and chart data.

How do I get the csv onto disk or even better stream it into the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should print content of object. Once you have the content, you can either put a tag on screen and dynamically generate click event that downloads the file, or parse the CSV content and use it for D3.

```
bucket.getObject({
    "Key": prefix
  }, function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(data.Body.toString());
  });
```

Comment: Ok great. `data.Body.toString()` does the job but had to put `"Bucket": bucketname` above `"Key": prefix` where "prefix" is  the name of the file in the bucket that I want. Is this the only way other than getting server involved? Also for those who, like me, were searching for this solution, will find this in AWS SDK Node.js solutions, while it is a general AWS SDK JavaScript solution.

Comment: So if only one bucket is involved, you can put that in class constructor, that way you don't have to provide `"Bucket": bucketname` in other operations (ie getObject, putObject etc). From my understanding AWS SDK for Node.js and Javascript is same. I may be wrong.

Comment: Can you update answer to show how to parse the CSV content and use it for D3?

Comment: @curtisp I would recommend using `papaparse` or something similar to parse the csv string to JSON object array.

Comment: I created new question with accepted answer for this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56998341/how-to-pass-javascript-object-to-another-function](here)