# How to pass JavaScript object to another function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am downloading csv file from AWS S3 bucket so that I can use it in D3.

No problem downloading the csv file. In code below the `console.log(data.Body.toString())` prints out the csv file contents in expected format

However, I am not sure how to pass the downloaded csv file content to D3 in code below.

The file contents are already in nice csv file format.

Question: how to replace `merged.csv` below with the `mergedcsv` object?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var bucket = new AWS.S3();

bucket.getObject({
    Bucket: 's3-google-analytics', 
    Key: 'merged.csv'
}, 
    function awsDataFile(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        mergedcsv = data.Body.toString();
        console.log(data.Body.toString());
    }
);

// how to replace the "merged.csv" below with the mergedcsv object above?

d3.csv("merged.csv", function(data) {
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;
    var counter = 0;
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        etc
    });
});

</script>
```

updated to add sample of `mergedcsv` content eg output of `console.log(mergedcsv);` or `console.log(data.Body.toString());` :

```
yyyymm,date,hostname,source,PPCC,in30days,sessionDuration,users,sessions,newUsers,twitterSessions,bounceRate,sessionsPerUser
201203,20120330,journal,google,PPCC,>30days,26.25,4,4,4,0,75.0,1.0
201203,20120331,journal,(direct),PPCC,>30days,0.0,3,3,3,0,100.0,1.0
201203,20120331,journal,bing,PPCC,>30days,0.0,1,1,1,0,100.0,1.0
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the structure of `mergedcsv`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading a the docs on d3.csv, it loads a CSV file from a URL, but in your example, you've already loaded the data, you just need to parse it. So d3.csv isn't going to be of any use.

It looks like the D3 function for parsing is `d3.csv.parse(data)` which will return an array of parsed data. (Docs are [here](https://d3-wiki.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/master/CSV/#parse))

So you could do something like…

```
var bucket = new AWS.S3();
var mergedcsv;

bucket.getObject({
    Bucket: 's3-google-analytics', 
    Key: 'merged.csv'
}, 
    function awsDataFile(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        mergedcsv = d3.csv.parse(data.Body.toString()); 

        // now mergedcsv will be an array, so you can do whatever you were going to do with it before, i.e...
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;
        var counter = 0;
        data.forEach(function(d) {
           etc
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Good catch on the scope problem, but I don't think that putting the object `mergedcsv` into `d3.csv` (which is expecting a URL in string form there) will work

Comment: Declared `var mergedcsv;` at top, then put `console.log(mergedcsv);` after `d3.csv(mergedcsv, function(data) {`   However nothing came out on console and it said `undefined` for that variable. But `console.log(mergedcsv);` after `mergedcsv = data.Body.toString();` does output to console. So didn't appear to put in scope?

Comment: Ha! I can't believe I didn't catch that! `mergedcsv` will only be populated after the callback fires at a future time. That call to d3.csv happens right afterward, so it will still be undefined. Also, reading d3.csv's docs states that it loads in from a URL so that wouldn't work anyway. I'll upload an answer that should work for you one sec…

Comment: Updated with a better answer. I saw docs that listed the csv parsing function as `d3.csv.parse()` and docs that listed it as `d3.csvParse()`. Try the second if the first isn't in your version.

Comment: Your previous answer was wrong, as you know, but this one is correct. FYI, OP is using D3 v3 (because of `d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;`), so the correct choice is `d3.csv.parse()` indeed. Also, I'd suggest you to link the original API: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/CSV.md#parse

Comment: Ok great thanks! that worked with one small change `data.forEach(function(d) {` to `mergedcsv.forEach(function(d) {`